# Indexes And Intent Shared Locks In Select Queries

Tags: sql-server

I did a simple `SELECT *` from a table using a `where` clause based on

1. The clustered index column
2. The nonclustered index column
3. A column with no index at all

Each time when I monitored the `Lock:Acquired` field in the SQL Profiler, I saw that in all three cases, first an `"Object"` type of `IS` lock is taken and then a "Page" type of `IS` lock is taken. When I queried the object via its `object id` using `select object_name(..)` it displayed the name of the table.

My question is, do all the three queries put an `Intent Shared` lock on the whole table? Shouldn't querying with columns having an index limit the lock to the specific row?

Comment: Does not your question answer itself?

Comment: @IvanStarostin I edited the last part of my question to clarify what I actually meant to ask.

Comment: It prevents other's intents to lock higher level object than involved in your transaction. If you have locked a `row`, could another transaction lock the `page` it lays on? But is the `page` locked by your transaction?

Comment: @IvanStarostin There is a Page lock I see in SQL Profiler for all the cases.